# vault permission denied from remote host

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I have very basic vault server with oob policies.
I can unseal server from remote host but when I call "vault secrets list" from remote host with root token I get "permission denied". 
In the same time when I call this command from local host all is ok.
Vault version - 1.2.3
What is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

It was a strange my own error - I had VAULT_TOKEN env variable with old wrong token.